# how to put data from text files to a pair?

Tags: c++, data-structures

The text file I am using has the following text:

```
3   4
5   6
```

And the output should come 2. It should count pairs.

```
while (getline(ifs, line)) {
        istringstream is(line);
        pair<int, int> p;
        ifs >> p.first;
        ifs >> p.second;
        cout << p.first << "  " << p.second<< endl;

        set<pair<int, int> > set1;
        }
```

Comment: Not `ifs >> p.first;` I think you want `is >> p.first;`. You are using the wrong stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be `is >> p.first;` and `is >> p.second;` you must read from stringstream(`is`) instead of the filestream(`ifs`)

Also just a sidenote, stop using `ifs`, `line`, `p`, etc and give them meaningful names. This not only aids YOU while programming, but also minimizes bugs, improves readability and makes you think in the right direction.

Comment: @user4032883 "It's not working" doesn't tell us much about your problem.

Comment: It is the whole method. And rest of the code do not have any thing do with it.